# DownloadImage when login

Tags: java, android, bitmapimage, android-bitmap

I've created an app where the user registers with his credentials and also uploads a profile picture. While logging the user enters his username,password and name of the image which he has uploaded. Till now the user is successfully able to register with his credentials along with his profile pic. I've stored the credentials of the user in the MySql while the image of the user is getting stored in the folder in the same server. Now when I'm trying to login, it gives me a `NullPointerException` and my app crashes. I don't know why this is happening, I've checked my code, I didn't find any error. I'm uploading it here. Please provide me with the answer. Thank you.

Login.java

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.bLogin:
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            String name1=etimagen.getText().toString();
            User user = new User(username, password,name1);
            DownloadImage di=new DownloadImage(etimagen.getText().toString());
            di.execute();

            authenticate(user);
            break;
        case R.id.tvRegisterLink:
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(registerIntent);
            break;
    }
}

private void authenticate(User user) {
    ServerRequests serverRequest = new ServerRequests(this);
    serverRequest.fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, new GetUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(User returnedUser) {
            if (returnedUser == null) {
                showErrorMessage();
            } else {
                logUserIn(returnedUser);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showErrorMessage() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Incorrect user details");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}

private void logUserIn(User returnedUser) {
    userLocalStore.storeUserData(returnedUser);
    userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
{

    String name1;

    public DownloadImage(String name1)
    {
        this.name1=name1;

    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


        String url=SERVER_ADDRESS + "pictures1/" + name1 + ".JPG";
        try
        {
            URLConnection connection=new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(1000*30);
            connection.setReadTimeout(1000*30);

            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) connection.getContent(),null,null);


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

@Override
    public void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if(bitmap!=null)
        {

            MainActivity main=new MainActivity();
            main.bitmap=bitmap;
            main.image();
        }




}




}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bLogout:
            userLocalStore.clearUserData();
            userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (authenticate() == true) {
        displayUserDetails();


    }
}





private boolean authenticate() {
    if (userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser() == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


private void displayUserDetails() {
    User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

    etUsername.setText(user.username);
    etName.setText(user.name);
    etAge.setText(user.age + "");


}

public Bitmap image() {
    image2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return bitmap;

}
```

}

**Error Log**

```
09-05 15:39:34.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 15:39:34.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4236): Process: com.example.loginregister, PID: 4236
09-05 15:39:34.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4236): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-05 15:39:34.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4236):     at com.example.loginregister.MainActivity.image(MainActivity.java:86)
09-05 15:39:34.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4236):     at com.example.loginregister.Login$DownloadImage.onPostExecute(Login.java:132)
09-05 15:39:34.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4236):     at com.example.loginregister.Login$DownloadImage.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
09-05 15:39:34.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4236):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
09-05 15:39:34.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4236):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-05 15:39:34.179: E/AndroidRuntime(4236):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
```

Comment: @rj ive put .. you can have a look

Comment: error is at line no 86 in MainActivity, but you haven't put whole code of MainActivity, its hard to understand

Comment: I've put tha main part

Comment: Whats at line `Login.java:132` &&  `MainActivity.java:86`

Comment: @Panther at Login.java:132-- main.image();

MainActivity.java:86-- image2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: @swapnilsaraf can you show me where & how you initialize `image2`

Comment: @Panther  
    ImageView image2;
    Button bLogout;
   DownloadImage login;
public Bitmap bitmap;
   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
        image2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);

Comment: ok. got the issue. Wait for my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with,

```
    public Bitmap image() {
    if(bitmap!=null)
        image2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Your bitmap object in null, that's why it is giving you NullPointerExcepition at line ,

```
            image2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Let me know if it works for you...
And mark it as an answer so that it would be useful to others...

Comment: show me the log, this time there must be some other error

Comment: i guess the problem is in main.image(), its not passing the onPostExecute 'bitmap' to MainActivity.. thats why its saying NullPointer Exception

Comment: yup, I guess so, you are creating a new instance of MainActivity and not referencing the one that is currently showing that's why its' not reflecting any change ..

Comment: i want to pass the onPostExecute bitmap in MainActivity,java, any idea ?

Comment: With this much of code, I don't understand the flow, please put whole code, you have said, Login.java, but what it is? a simple class or activiity? Can't understand anything. Put complete code of these two files.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i assume you are a beginner for Android Development.

You are trying to download the user image and display it on `MainActivity`.
There is two issues with the architecture.

- First

  The below piece of code initiates two async request. There is no guarantee that the image request will complete after login or vice versa. I suggest you to place the image request inside `MainActivity` after ensuring the user has successfully logged in. Meaning, place it after `authenticate(user)` success.

  ```
      User user = new User(username, password,name1);
      DownloadImage di=new DownloadImage(etimagen.getText().toString());
      di.execute();
      authenticate(user);
  ```
- Second

The below piece of code creates a new instance of `MainActivity` and tries to assigns the retrieved bitmap to `ImageView`. One must know that `onCreate` gets executed just before the activity is displayed. It wont be called when `new MainActivity()` is done. So there is no chance of `image2` being set with a value. Which is why you are getting the error.

```
    public void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        {
            MainActivity main=new MainActivity();
            main.bitmap=bitmap;
            main.image();
        }
    }
```

I assume since you want to set the image somewhere on `MainActivity`, you should make the image request inside `MainActivity` probably in `onCreate`.

Also this `startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));` in method `login` will start a new activity. This is completly different `MainActivity` instance from the one you are creating in `onPostExecute`.
Pass the image url via `bundle extra` to activity, retrieve it in `onCreate`, make the image call and display it on the imageView.

Hope this helps :) ::)

Comment: Hi @Panther, I really appreciate your effort, yes im a begginer in Android development. The points you mentioned above are quite helpful. I'm a begginer so im getting confused as to where to make changes in the file. Can can you please do me a favour by making changes in the above files as youve mentioned. It would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: And also please tell me how do I pass the image URL ?